# Column visibility SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table that has 3 Row Groups. The order is `Customer` > `Group` > `Colour`

I want the report to show all customers, and then you can expand to reveal groups associated with that customer and then expand the groups to show the colour's.

Now I am pretty sure I know how this is done....

I have selected `group properties` on `Group` from inside the row group panel, and changed the visibility properties to `Hide` and then toggled on `Customer`. I have also changed the visibility properties after selecting `Colour` and toggled on `Group`. This has all been done on the row group panel, nothing changed on text boxes within the actual tablix.

The report however shows no data whatsoever.

If i change the visibility of `Colour` to be toggled by `Customer` and change `Group` to `Show` then the data shows again. This is not how I want the table to appear.

Is there a known issue with SSRS? I have added one of the Row Groups after initially only having 2, and previously the toggle was working as required. It seems that after I have added the 3rd group, altering the toggle properties just doesn't seem to work.

**Do I need to rebuild the table from scratch to get it behaving as required Or am i missing something?**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are doing is correct. Each group except the top level group should be set to `Hidden=True` and the toggle item should be the name of the textbox you want to click on to expand/collapse, this would usually be the textbox in the parent group.

I've done a very simple example and it works as expected so you may want to compare the grouping with the image below and make sure each groups cells are on distinct rows in the table.

Note: The detail group here has no grouping.

So the details group is hidden and its toggleitem is `SuperCategoryDesc` which is the cell from it's parent. The SuperCategory Group is hidden and its toggle item is `CategoryGroupDesc`.

If you still have no luck, post your current design.

[image]